# Get multiple data from tables Using Entity Framework data model

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework model data to manipulate data from database (CRUD operations). I want to get all data from tables (not just one).

Here is database model:

[image: Database model]

I want to get multiple data from all tables.

Currently I am using query displayed bellow but problem with this query is that I got multiple values from Contact tables and other tables displays only one result. Does someone knows why my query is not working and how to get all multiple data from tables.

Here is Query/Function to get all data from database:

```
ContactsEntities db = new ContactsEntities();
        //get all contacts
        public JsonResult GetAll()
        {
            var data = (from c in db.Contacts
                        from e in db.Emails.Where(x => x.id == c.id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from p in db.Phones.Where(x => x.id == c.id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        from t in db.Tags.Where(x => x.id == c.id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            id = c.id,
                            phones = p.number,
                            emails = e.email1,
                            tags = t.tag1,
                            firstname = c.firstname,
                            lastname = c.lastname,
                            address = c.address,
                            city = c.city,
                            bookmarked = c.bookmarked,
                            notes = c.notes
                        }).ToList();
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Why you don't establish relationship between your entities?

Comment: I will add them latter. I just started with ASP.NET and MS SQL server so I currently don't know how to do that. Also, I need to finish other "stuffs" and relationships are not that crucial at this moment @aria

Comment: Use join because "id_contact" is related.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have tested this on your model it works:

```
var test1 = (from c in db.Contacts
                   join e in db.Emails
                       on c.id equals e.id_contact
                   join t in db.Tags
                   on c.id equals t.id_contact
                   join p in db.Phones on c.id equals p.id_contact
                   select new
                   {
                       id = c.id,
                       phones = p.number,
                       emails = e.email1,
                       tags = t.tag1,
                       firstname = c.firstname,
                       lastname = c.lastname,
                       address = c.address,
                       city = c.city,
                       bookmarked = c.bookmarked,
                       notes = c.notes
                   }).ToList();
```

I was trying to resolve this in one step, otherwise add this after test1 it works properly:

```
 var result = (from contact in test1
                    group contact by contact.id into grp
                    select new
                    {
                        id = grp.Key,
                        firstname = grp.First().firstname,
                        lastname = grp.First().lastname,
                        address = grp.First().address,
                        city = grp.First().city,
                        bookmarked = grp.First().bookmarked,
                        notes = grp.First().notes,
                        phones = grp.Where(x => x.phones != null).Select(x => x.phones).Distinct().ToArray(),
                        emails = grp.Where(x => x.emails != null).Select(x => x.emails).Distinct().ToArray(),
                        tags = grp.Where(x => x.tags != null).Select(x => x.tags).Distinct().ToArray()
                    }).ToList();
```

If you establish the relation between them it will be resolved and this code will return all contacts as you want:

1- Create New Diagram

2- Add these tables and then Drag Contact's id on 'id_contact' of each Email,Tag and phone

3- Save the diagram on Sql Server

4- Recreate your Model in Visual Studio

[image: Relation]

```
var contacts = (from c in db.Contacts
                       select c).ToList();
```

for each contact it will get all related emails,phones and tags just by the relation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code is working but I got 4 results with same data from Contacts and different data for each tables besides Contacts. Is there way to group Emails/Tags/Phones data to array and send to frontend like that?

Comment: I tried your code and I added Foreign keys to tables but I don't get all data from Phones/Tags or Emails tables...

Comment: Thank you @aria. I added your code it's working nice but with one problem. It displays only one result. I need all data from contact table.

Comment: Yes by the second query the contacts they have not details in child tables will not show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67757/discussion-between-aria-and-jureispro).

Answer (score 1):

You're linking x.id to c.id. I think you need to link x.id_contact to c.id. (same problem for phone & tag)

```
        var data = (from c in db.Contacts
                    from e in db.Emails.Where(x => x.id_contact == c.id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from p in db.Phones.Where(x => x.id_contact == c.id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from t in db.Tags.Where(x => x.id_contact == c.id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        id = c.id,
                        phones = p.number,
                        emails = e.email1,
                        tags = t.tag1,
                        firstname = c.firstname,
                        lastname = c.lastname,
                        address = c.address,
                        city = c.city,
                        bookmarked = c.bookmarked,
                        notes = c.notes
                    }).ToList();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Judging by the 'phones', 'emails' and 'tags' properties of the select, i'm thinking you expect 1 record per contact. You can achieve this with a group by:

```
       var data = (from c in db.Contacts
                from e in db.Emails.Where(x => x.id_contact == c.id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from p in db.Phones.Where(x => x.id_contact == c.id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from t in db.Tags.Where(x => x.id_contact == c.id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    id = c.id,
                    phone = (p != null ? p.number : null),
                    email = (e != null ? e.email1 : null),
                    tag = (t != null ? t.tag1 : null),
                    firstname = c.firstname,
                    lastname = c.lastname,
                    address = c.address,
                    city = c.city,
                    bookmarked = c.bookmarked,
                    notes = c.notes
                }).ToList();

        var data2 = (from i in data
                    group i by i.id into grp
                    select new
                    {
                        id = grp.Key,
                        phones = grp.Where(x => x.phone != null).Select(x => x.phone).ToArray(),
                        emails = grp.Where(x => x.email != null).Select(x => x.email).ToArray(),
                        tags = grp.Where(x => x.tag != null).Select(x => x.tag).ToArray(),
                        firstname = grp.First().firstname,
                        lastname = grp.First().lastname,
                        address = grp.First().address,
                        city = grp.First().city,
                        bookmarked = grp.First().bookmarked,
                        notes = grp.First().notes
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't have email_id, phone_id and tag_id in Contacts table

Comment: You're right. It's the other way around. Edited reply.

Comment: Thank you for help. I used updated code but I am getting same rows (4 rows with same data).

Comment: 4 rows, but with different contact info probably... I updated my reply to group those results per contact.

Comment: I have 4 rows with same data from Contacts and different date in each table data that's inside tables like Emails, Phones or Tags. Is there way to group result from Emails/Phones/Tags in array and put that array to list of contacts?

Comment: Contacts table can have multiple phones/emails/tags

Comment: Did you use the last query? (the one with the `group new ...`)

Comment: it trows me error:

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] ToArray[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67753/discussion-between-jureispro-and-codemonkey).

Answer (score 0):

If the external key is the contacts in all other tables, the following code will work in C# - EntityFramework6 - MVC5 :

```
var conts= db.Contacts;
db.Entry(conts).Collection(c => c.Emails).Load();
// If you retrieve an email, use "Reference" instead of "Collection"
```

Entity Framework Documentation :

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
   var post = context.Posts.Find(2);

   // Load the blog related to a given post
   context.Entry(post).Reference(p => p.Blog).Load();

   // Load the blog related to a given post using a string
   context.Entry(post).Reference("Blog").Load();

   var blog = context.Blogs.Find(1);

   // Load the posts related to a given blog
   context.Entry(blog).Collection(p => p.Posts).Load();

   // Load the posts related to a given blog
   // using a string to specify the relationship
   context.Entry(blog).Collection("Posts").Load();
}
```